# DAX subtotal not adding correctly

Tags: excel, dax, powerpivot

I have writen a dax expression that calculates it right but when I apply `year`  as a filter the subtotal goes wrong. The measure:

```
CALCULATE (
    SUMX ( sales; sales[salesvalue] );
    SUMMARIZE (
        FILTER (
            clients;
            CALCULATE ( SUMX ( discount; discount[value] ); discount[value] > 0 )
        );
        client[client_code]
    )
)
```

Sample Data and relationship:

[image]

[image]

Any help on a fix for this issue ?

Thanks

Comment: Can you show some sample data, the result you are getting, and the desired result?

Comment: Hi Alexis, there are 3 tables connected by cliente_code ( cliente info, sales and discount ). The summarize function is just filtering the clientes that have discount > 0. The problem is that the subtotal is wrong :(

Comment: Without the information I requested, it's difficult to help. Your comment didn't provide additional information not already in the post. Please edit your post as necessary.

Comment: Hi Alexis, I have added a picture with the data. Basically the Total is using the filters on the measure therefore the total is not adding up correctly.

Comment: It looks like what's happening is that the total is calculating the sum of sales for every client that has a discount in at least one month and keeping their sales for the months where there was no discount. This is difficult to fix without seeing the relationship diagram.

Comment: Hi, yes, the measure calculates for every month the sales for each client that has discount in that particular month. However that client might not have a discount in some months but the total is considering the sales for all months. I have added the relationship so you can see it.

Comment: I have searched for solutions and some mentioned a fix using HASONEFILTER but I haven't been able to use it right. Thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to do the filtering within your `SUMX` iteration.

Try something along these lines:

```
SUMX (
    sales;
    sales[salesvalue]
    * IF(
          LOOKUPVALUE(
              discount[value],
              discount[date], sales[date],
              discount[client_code], sales[client_code]
          ) > 0,
         1,
         0
      )
)
```

You might be able to use `RELATED` instead of `LOOKUPVALUE`, but the latter should work even if the relationships aren't quite set up for `RELATED` to work as you'd expect.